# Convolution2D gives wrong output shape in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, theano, convolution

I'm following tutorial from [here](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) and have stuck with simple model creation

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 28, 28)))
model.output_shape
```

This should give `(None, 32, 26, 26)` output but instead I get `(None, -1, 26, 32)`. I guess something wrong with parameters provided or I need to make additional reshape. Maybe something has been changed for `Convolution2D` and `Conv2D` in Keras? I'm running `2.2.4` with `Theano` backend

Comment: I get InvalidArgumentError with your code.

Comment: @Tzomas check keras version you are running, probably you have old one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the channels are in the first axis of input data. Therefore, you need to set `data_format` argument to `"channels_first"`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                        data_format='channels_first',
                        activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 28, 28)))
model.output_shape
```

Which gives:

```
(None, 32, 26, 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it uses Theano as a backend and probably you are using tensorflow (you should check your setting once again). You can change it with:

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
```

This should be done before importing `keras`

Answer (score 0):

Well like I wrote in my comment. I got a error with your code. So see that it looks like you have bad shape on input, if you change to `input_shape=(28,28,1)` then output_shape returns `(None, 26, 26, 32)`

I don't know if this is what you are exactly looking for.